# Make a component optionally controlled or uncontrolled

Tags: reactjs

So I am trying to create this Collapse component either controlled or uncontrolled, optionally, depending on how its used, but that is quickly becoming a headache.

```
export const Collapse = ({
  ExpandIcon = StyledExpandIcon,
  CollapseIcon = StyledCollapseIcon,
  expanded = false,
  noButton = false,
  ...props
}) => {
  const [isExpanded, setIsExpanded] = useState(expanded);

  const handleSetExpanded = () => {
    setIsExpanded((prevState) => !prevState);
  };

  return (
    <>
      {!noButton && (
        <StyledIconButton onClick={handleSetExpanded}>
          {isExpanded ? <CollapseIcon /> : <ExpandIcon />}
        </StyledIconButton>
      )}

      <StyledCollapse in={expanded} {...props} />
    </>
  );
};
```

So I can't figure out how to make the `useState` optional, if the component is controlled, then its `expanded` state should be set somewhere outside of it, at the same time, both `expanded` and `noButton` should become required props, should either of them be supplied, so if I have suppplied only `expanded` then `noButton` should also be required, so that I remove the "default" button, same goes for first `noButton`.

I am pretty sure I can come up with some weird messed up logic and make it work, but what is the general way of doing something like this?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is your component being able to handle both controlled & uncontrolled values, right? This might not be on point to what use-case you might want. But in this case,

- Add a variable to validate if your component is controlled/uncontrolled. You can check with `const isControlled = expanded == null;`
- add an if statement to your `handleSetExpanded` to only call your `setIsExpanded` only if `isControlled` is false.
- For your `StyledCollapse` && the inside of your `StyledIconButton` , you can pass a state of `expanded || isExpanded`. In that case, if expanded is null/undefined, then we'd be basing our value off of the state of your Collapse instead of the prop. Or better yet, can be `isControlled ? expanded : isExpanded`
- Add warnings to your component (if not on prod)

This is what the code should look like.

```
export const Collapse = ({
  ExpandIcon = StyledExpandIcon,
  CollapseIcon = StyledCollapseIcon,
  expanded = false,
  noButton = false,
  ...props
}) => {
  const [isExpanded, setIsExpanded] = useState(expanded)
  const isControlled = expanded == null

  const handleSetExpanded = () => {
    if (!isControlled) {
      setIsExpanded(prevState => !prevState)
    }
  }

  if (isControlled && !noButton && process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    React.useEffect(() => {
      console.warning(
        `You cannot use "expanded" prop without the "noButton" prop for the Collapse`,
      )
    }, [isControlled, noButton])
  }

  return (
    <>
      {!noButton && (
        <StyledIconButton onClick={handleSetExpanded}>
          {expanded || isExpanded ? <CollapseIcon /> : <ExpandIcon />}
        </StyledIconButton>
      )}

      <StyledCollapse in={expanded || isExpanded} {...props} />
    </>
  )
}
```

Hope the code helps you or the bullet points at least guide you to what you want your code to look like! (Might I also point you to a [Kent C Dodds talk that might guide you](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AiJ8tRRH0f8) in the future)